How are missing values dealt with in the MBESS package in R?
I am currently calculating McDonald's Omega for my scales in R. The literature suggests using the ci.reliability function from the MBESS package to obtain confidence intervals. However, I haven't found any documentation on how MBESS handles missing values. I would appreciate any information regarding this issue.

This would depend on which calculation you're asking it to do exactly (the documentation specifies at least 30 or so different CIs?). The default seem to be a lavaan confirmatory factor analysis with maximum likelihood imputation of missing values.
